# Select duplicates within multiple groups

Tags: sql, group-by

Using the following table:

StoreId INT PRIMARY KEY,
CustomerId INT,
StoreName VARCHAR

I need a single select statement that will tell me if any CustomerId has duplicate StoreName entries.

Example, given this data:

```
StoreId | CustomerId | StoreName
1       | 25         | "Store 6"
2       | 42         | "Downtown"
3       | 101        | "Store 22"
4       | 33         | "South Valley"
5       | 42         | "Store Five"
6       | 33         | "South Valley"
7       | 215        | "Downtown"
```

I need a query that returns

```
CustomerId | StoreName
33         | "South Valley"
```

Because customer number 33 has two stores both named "South Valley". But having two stores named "Downtown" won't show up in the results because they are from two different customers.

I don't want to use a cursor or a loop if possible. I'm trying to find a way to do it with `SELECT` and `GROUP BY`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I removed the extraneous database tags.  Feel free to tag the question with the database you are actually using.

Comment: Why remove the tags? If someone is new to SQL Server, and has a similar question, they're going to search by 'sql-server' and 'group-by'. At the same time, if someone has the same question, but is using MySQL, they're going to search by 'mysql' and 'group-by'.

Comment: Also, those who downvoted my question, please explain why. If I should have worded it better, please explain what I did wrong, so I can post better questions. If you just downvoted the question because you think it's an easy question, why would you do that?

Comment: . . First, I didn't downvote the question.  Second, you have enough reputation that you should know how tags work.  The "sql" tag is generic.  The other tags are for specific databases.

Comment: I do know how tags work. They exist so people can find answers by topic. From the perspective of a searcher, both "mysql" and "sql-server" are valid tags, because if you're coming from either platform, you might easily search by one or the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
   CustomerId, StoreName
from tab
group by CustomerId, StoreName
having count(*) > 1
```